# Using CASE in WHERE clause that uses the existing value of a column to compare to value returned from JSON_VALUE?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've got this query:

```
UPDATE MyThing
SET BeginCheckDate = JSON_VALUE(components.value, '$.values[1]')
FROM [dbo].[MyThing] e
    INNER JOIN MyThingData ed ON e.Id = ed.MyThingId
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (ed.Content, '$.views[0].sections[0].components') components
WHERE ISJSON(ed.Content) > 0
-- begin part that matters for my question
    AND (JSON_VALUE(components.value, '$.id') =
      (CASE
        WHEN e.DesignType = 'Change Compensation' THEN @compensationBeginCheckDateId
        WHEN e.DesignType = 'Change Leave of Absence' THEN @leaveOfAbsenceBeginCheckDateId
        WHEN e.DesignType = 'Change Position' THEN @positionBeginCheckDateId
        WHEN e.DesignType = 'Change Reactivate' THEN @reactivateBeginCheckDateId
        WHEN e.DesignType = 'Change Rehire' THEN @rehireBeginCheckDateId
        WHEN e.DesignType = 'Change Termination' THEN @terminationBeginCheckDateId
      END)
-- end part that matters for my question
    AND LEN(value) > @minimumLengthForJsonContainingDates
```

In the WHERE clause, I want to use different variables depending on the existing value of the "DesignType" column. I'm trying to use CASE WHEN THEN, but I'm getting a non-helpful `Incorrect syntax near '@minimumLengthForJsonContainingDates'` error

Comment: `ISJSON(ed.Content)` in the `WHERE` is somewhat pointless, when the call to `OPENJSON` has likely errored is it *isn't* valid.

Comment: you are missing a parenthesis after `END)`. If I understood correctly, should be `END))`

Comment: As for the error, you're missing a right parenthesis (`)`). There's no need to wrap all your expressions in parentheses, so, in all honesty, you could remove them all (excluded the ones required for function parameters).

Comment: @Lamak and Larnu I feel like an idiot for missing something so obvious. Thank you.

Comment: @Larnu Thank you for pointing that out about ISJSON. Getting rid of it actually improved the speed of my script quite a bit.

Comment: @Larnu That's not entirely true. The `WHERE` is highly likely to be evaluated first as it is on the base table, however it's not guaranteed, and there is almost no way to guarantee that it will be so.

Comment: You can use a searched `CASE` so `CASE e.DesignType WHEN 'Change Compensation' THEN ...` although with that many I would consider a join on a `VALUES` table